# pandas numpy error:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe you can have it by following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df4s = """
    contract  RB  BeginDate  
0  A00118     46   20120705      
1  A00118     47   20121005      
2  A00253     48   0             
3  A00253     48   0                     
"""
df4 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df4s.strip()), sep='\s+', 
                  dtype={"BeginDate": int}
                  )
```

The output is:

```
contract    RB  BeginDate
0   A00118  46  20120705
1   A00118  47  20121005
2   A00253  48  0
3   A00253  48  0
```

Now I want to generate a new header 'first_month' based on the 'BeginDate',the logic is simple,
if the BeginDate equals 0 then first_month will be 0,or it will equals to the month value of the BeginDate,my code is:

```
df4['first_month'] = np.where(df4['BeginDate'] != 0,
                                    df4['BeginDate'].astype(str).str[4:6:1].astype(int), 0)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The error track is:

```
:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
    707         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987
    708         if np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
--> 709             return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
    710 
    711         # if we have a datetime/timedelta array of objects

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

pandas/_libs/src\util.pxd in util.set_value_at_unsafe()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The output should be:

```
contract    RB  BeginDate  first_month
0   A00118  46  20120705   7
1   A00118  47  20121005   10
2   A00253  48  0          0
3   A00253  48  0          0
```

Any friend can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `np.where`:

> x, y, array_like
> Values from which to choose. x, y and condition need to be broadcastable to some shape.

It means your operation for x is not evaluated only when condition is true but selected when condition is true. Therefore your operation is performed on the whole dataframe not on the subset (2 first rows). That's why you raised this error on the third row.

Use `zfill` to transform a '0' to '00000000':

```
df4['first_month'] = df4['BeginDate'].astype(str).str.zfill(8).str[4:6:1].astype(int)
print(df4)

# Output
  contract  RB  BeginDate  first_month
0   A00118  46   20120705            7
1   A00118  47   20121005           10
2   A00253  48          0            0
3   A00253  48          0            0
```

Comment: @William. I updated my answer. Can you check it please? I hope my explanation are clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas dataframes can be filtered directly

```
df4[df4.BeginDate != 0]
```

or

```
df4.loc[df4.BeginDate != 0]
```

You can then just add on your logic to extract the date

```
df4['first_month'] = df4.loc[df4.BeginDate != 0].BeginDate.astype(str).str[4:6:1].astype(int)
```

Note that this will put 'NAN's in rows 2 and 3 not '0' like in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but I need the row2 and row3 be 0.

Comment: It should be straightforward to replace the NaNs with 0. I am no expert on the best way to do the replacement, but this seems to work (with a warning raised) 
`df4.first_month[df4.first_month.isnull().values] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Given the BeginDate column contains string objects you can achieve your desired results with:

```
df['FirstMonth'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row['BeginDate'] == '0' else int(row['BeginDate'][4:6]), axis = 1)
```

This yields:

```
    Contract    RB  BeginDate   FirstMonth
0   A00118  46  20120705    7
1   A00118  47  20121005    10
2   A00253  48  0   0
3   A00253  48  0   0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,but the apply function runs very slow, especially when data size is large.

Comment: That is a piece of information that would have been nice to include in your problem statement.  I guess if you are working with df's larger than 1000 rows that might be a consideration.